# Visual studio 2013 "hangs" for a while when Exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Ult.) with Windows 8.1 (Ent.). Visual Studio 2013 is acting really strange: When exception is thrown VS2013 "hangs" for a while (30 - 75 seconds!!!) and then "Exception was unhandled" window appear.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing Exception...");
        throw new Exception("Test");
    }
```

VS takes about 20 seconds to react on exception...

When debuging project in which I use dependency injection, this time increases to minutes - what makes VS2013 unusable...

The above code reacts normal on VS2012 (same computer)...
Computer is using I7 CPU with 16GB of ram, so I presume that HW isn't a problem...

How to fix this / find out what is wrong? I all-ready disabled IntelliTrace...

Comment: It indeed does.  There are some fit-and-finish flaws in VS2013, the next Update no doubt will fix some of them.  The delays you get are unusual, use connect.microsoft.com to report the issue.

Comment: No-repro here. Win 8 x64, i7, 16gb ddr3. IntelliTrace enabled.

Comment: Which extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Only VisualSVN (I made a clean install; Win 8.1 Ent + VS2013) and Resharper (v.8.0.2). Installed extentions or not, it doesn't make a difference (uninstalled all)... I really have to find work around because this is killing me... :(

Answer (score 0):

As Hans mentioned, this appears to be a bug in 2013 please log it through https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=5303&FeedbackType=1